# Postfix domain renaming with several domains

Tags: postfix-mta, mail-server, dovecot

I configured a complete mail server with postfix and dovecot.
Im running multiple domains on it that means thats I have several email with different domains for example :

hello@domain1.com
hello@domain2.com
hello@domain3.com

What I want now is instead of using

```
    MX domain1.com
    MX domain2.com
    MX domain3.com
```

use :

```
    MX mail.domain1.com
    MX mail.domain2.com
    MX mail.domain3.com
```

BUT my email should be still

```
    hello@domain1.com
    hello@domain2.com
    hello@domain3.com
```

so, for a single domain configuration you should do in the /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
    myhostname = mail.domain1.com
    mydomain = domain1.com
```

but as I use multiple domain my configuration is a bit different.

My current configuration is the following :

```
    myhostname = domain1.com
    mydomain = domain1.com
    
    virtual_alias_domains = domain2.com domain3.com
    virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

in /etc/postfix/virtual I have :

```
    hello@domain1.com hellofirstdomain
    hello@domain2.com helloseconddomain
    hello@domain3.com hellothirddomain
    other@domain1.com otherfirstdomain
    other@domain2.com otherseconddomain
```

and so on...

SO, How can I use mail.domain1.com mail.domain2.com mail.domain2.com hostname but keep only domainX.com for my emails ?

Thanks you in advance

I read the postfix documentation but I can't find what I exactly want.